# Use automated web browser in mobile app

Tags: android, ios, selenium, web

I was wondering if anyone could let me know if this can be done, and anything that could it. What I want to do from a mobile app (android or ios) is to navigate to a webpage fill out a login form and then login to that web service from a mobile app.

I was looking at selenium as something that might be able to do this, but it seems it is limited to just my machine? Am I correct in that it has to be installed on my android device, and I could not have a program that would run on a deployed app.

So that it would navigate, to the web age, fill out the form and then click th login button?

Thanks for the help in.

Answer (score 0):

Look at appium: http://appium.io/getting-started.html

> Appium is an open source, cross-platform test automation tool for native, hybrid and mobile web apps, tested on simulators (iOS, FirefoxOS), emulators (Android), and real devices (iOS, Android, FirefoxOS).

Comment: right, so just to make sure I would be able to go to a website (in background) the user would give me username and password, i would then log them in, and grab some data from the site to display to them, and could release this on app store?

Comment: Release on the app store? Doubtful. But I'm confused on what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood your question-
You want to do some action "Login" from your mobile app but before that from your device you want to 
- go to mobile web browser - >possible using appium with selenium
- launch a webpage and fill some data - > possible using appium with selenium
- Grab some data from this webpage-> possible using appium with selenium
- Use the grabbed data in your app - > again appium

Yes, you can use android device or emulator(android sdk or genymotion) to run this script. Should work in a similar way from iOS as well.